# Como instalar PngComponents Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Tags: delphi

Olá eu fiz download do PngComponents nesse [link](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26127)  tentei instalar ele no install components do delphi mas ele não funcionou, se alguem conseguir me ajudar eu ficaria muito grato.

Ele fica listado em packages mas quando crio um projeto o componente não aparece, sou iniciante no Delphi e acho que não instalei corretamente o componente.
[image: PngComponents]

Comment: Cara, eu percebi que no package existe o PngComponents e o PngComponentsDesign, por acaso você instalou este último?

Comment: instalei ele mesmo assim não aparece, depois de instalar os packages devo fazer algo á mais?

Comment: Cara, eu honestamente nunca instalei componentes pelo instalador do Delphi. Se fosse você tentaria instalar manualmente que teria mais sucesso.

Comment: Código-fonte sempre mais atualizado neste link: https://github.com/TurboPack/PNGComponents

Answer (score 2):

Já instalei esse componente em diversas versões do Delphi. Posso te orientar como instalar.

Você precisa seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Quando você baixa este componente do site da Embarcadero, ele vem num arquivo compactado correto? Então você extrai ele em uma pasta.

   *Digamos que você extraiu em C:\Delphi\Componentes\PNG*
2. No caso do Delphi Berlin, dentro desta pasta haverá uma pasta chamada **PackagesBerlin**.
   Com o Delphi aberto, você vai no comando de abrir (tanto faz qual o comando de abrir) e vai até esta pasta, e especifica o arquivo **PngComponentsGroup.groupproj**
3. Com esse pacote aberto no Delphi, você vai até o Project Manager (normalmente no lado direito do Delphi), e estarão listados lá dois Packages.
   Você deve selecionar o primeiro item da lista: **PngComponentsGroup**, então você clica com o lado direito do mouse e escolhe **Build All**.
4. Então você localiza nesta mesma lista o pacote **PngComponentsDesign** (o ícone é uma caixa igual ao outro pacote, porém possui um símbolo em cinza em cima desta caixa).
   Clica com lado direito neste pacote e escolhe **Install**.
   Irá aparecer uma mensagem dizendo que os componentes foram registrados na IDE do Delphi.
   Pode clicar no botão **Save All** e fechar todo o group proj usando a função **Close All**.
5. Agora você deve ir até o menu **Tools**, e escolha o item **Options**. Localize na lista da esquerda o item **Environment Options\Delphi Options\Library**. A menos que você vá utilizar plataforma 64 bits, selecione na direita 32 bits no primeiro combobox.
   Então logo em seguida na caixa Library Path, clique no botão ao lado direito (...).
   Localize a mesma pasta PackagesBerlin de antes. Dentro desta pasta deverá ter uma pasta chamada Win32, e dentro desta deverá conter uma chamada Release. É esta pasta que você deve especificar (seguindo a pasta de exemplo lá do início, ficaria: C:\Delphi\Componentes\PNG\PackagesBerlin\Win32\Release), e então clicar em **Add**, e depois em **OK**.
   De volta a tela Options, pode também clicar em **OK**.

Pronto! O componente está pronto para ser utilizado.